# How to write into a csv with multiple rows and columns

Tags: node.js

Now I have several JSON in my mongodb, such as:

```
{
   title: "title_1",
   content: "content_1",
   author: "author_1"
}
```

And I want to write these data into a csv file with the format below:

```
title    content     author
title_1  content_1   author_1
title_2  content_2   author_2
...
```

I used the node-csv-parser module. But it always write in only the first column in the csv file, such as:

```
title                          content          author
title_1,content_1,author_1
title_1,content_1,author_2
...
```

What should I do to achieve my aim? Please show me some examples. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert to nested arrays, join.

```
var array = [
  {
    title: "title_1",
    content: "content_1",
    author: "author_1"
  },
  {
    title: "title_1",
    content: "content_1",
    author: "author_2"
  }
];
var keys = Object.keys(array[0]);
var csv = [keys.join('\t')];
array.forEach(function (data) {
  var row = [];
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    row.push(data[key]);
  });
  csv.push(row.join('\t'));
});
csv = csv.join('\n');
```

output:

```
title   content author
title_1 content_1   author_1
title_1 content_1   author_2
```

Comment: And then? What should I do to write it into multiple columns in a csv file?

Comment: do, you mean all tab delimited? I adjusted my example to use tabs.

Comment: What module do you use? I use the node-csv-parser module, but the tab doesn't work.

Comment: Oh! I got it! It's the difference between operating systems. The csv file displays one column in ubuntu, and displays multiple columns in windows.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link to generate your json or csv vice-versa

http://www.cparker15.com/code/utilities/csv-to-json/

I hope this will be useful to you.

Thanks.